# How do I wrap HWND and HINSTANCE types with SWIG?

Tags: python, c++, c, types, swig

I'm wrapping a third-party provided Windows DLL with SWIG for use in Python.  I have been able to successfully compile my SWIG module and import it into Python, but I'm running into issues with one function (from the `.h` header file):

```
_APPFN ServerID _CALLCONV OpenServer(HINSTANCE hAppInst, HWND hWnd);
```

I'm running into issues using this function, because I don't have types for `HINSTANCE` or `HWND` in Python.  Per the documentation for this function, these values can be null, 0, or basically anything (currently an unused feature), so I'm trying to figure out how to use `typemap` to make these integers so I can just pass in 0s.  From my `.i` file:

```
/* handle HINSTANCE */
%typemap(in) HINSTANCE {
    $1 = PyInt_AsLong($input);
}

/* handle hwnds */
%typemap(in) HWND {
    $1 = PyInt_AsLong($input);
}
```

When I try to compile my wrapper file (I'm using Visual Studio) with the above typemaps, I get errors: `cannot convert from 'long' to 'HINSTANCE'` and `cannot convert from 'long' to 'HWND'`.

Based on my reading, I believe that `HINSTANCE` and `HWND` are "structs", and so I need to do something in order to "cast" the struct to an integer, but unfortunately, this is all really above my head.  I'm mostly a self-taught Python programmer, and dealing with C/C++ data typing is rather confusing.

I'm hoping that someone can look at what I'm doing, and guide me on how I need to change my typemapping.

Comment: I know nothing about typemap thingy, but abovementioned types are just ints. At least they were ints last time I had used windows. If you compiling a C code, you could, with a glance at win32 headers, typedef these types as int. In python... I just do not know how to do a cast. Never thought of it. Maybe int(value) will do?

Comment: According to msdn [windows data types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog/windows-data-types), they are pointers
```typedef void *PVOID;
typedef PVOID HANDLE;
typedef HANDLE HWND;
```
_void*_ pointers to be more precise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These types are `void*`s per the Microsoft documentation:
  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winprog/windows-data-types

Although to be sure, cppyy (through Clang parsing the Windows headers) resolves them as pointers to opaque types (i.e. forward declared, but not defined):

```
$ python
>>> import cppyy
>>> print(cppyy.gbl.HWND)
<cppyy.TypedefPointerToClass object at 0x00000245E8839558>
>>>
```

so you may want to look up the typedefs if you want to know for sure.

However, regardless whether HWND and HINSTANCE are pointers to opaque classes or pointers to `void`, even as you could cast them on 32b Windows, on 64b casting from `long` to `void*` (or "`opaque*`") won't work because the `long` value will have been truncated. So, use `PyLong_AsVoidPtr` instead of `PyInt_AsLong` in your typemap. See the Python C-API documentation:
  https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/long.html#c.PyLong_AsVoidPtr

If the types are of opaque classes, you will also need the explicit cast, and the final code would look like:

```
/* handle HINSTANCE */
%typemap(in) HINSTANCE {
    $1 = (HINSTANCE)PyLong_AsVoidPtr($input);
}

/* handle hwnds */
%typemap(in) HWND {
    $1 = (HWND)PyLong_AsVoidPtr($input);
}
```

Of course, if both `HWND` and `HINSTANCE` are indeed `void*` as per that Microsoft documentation page, then that cast will be a no-op.